# Prepending Wildcard (*) for a Path in Apple App Site Association File

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-app-site-associate

We have an url like www.domain.com/{locale}/article/slug.

Here can I use path like `*/article/*` ?

`local` refers to language code, i.e. EN, HI.

Comment: Yes, just use `/*/article/*`